# automatically adjust div with proper gaping and width when we resize the window by using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive

I need to set div with an equal margin when we resize the window screen. we can set in mobile view its show one div and tablet 2 div ? is it possible to set flex?

Note: no need to set a responsive media query for this task.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flexcontainer-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30.33%;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 3%;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
</div>
```

note: I was mention that no need gap of the last div.

[image]

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. Do you want to center a div on desktop view ?

Comment: set: flex: 1; in your flex item class. You can also use: justify-content: space-between; on flex container

Comment: @UtsavPatel dear, I was mention in question what I want exactly.

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH `set div with an equal margin when we resize the window screen`

This essentially means centering a div. A div with equal margins on both sides will be in the center of the screen.

Comment: @Isisco when we set flex:1 in flex item classes its display one row of all flex item. it's the wrong way.

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH do you want the boxes in a row to touch the start and end point of the screen or it wont be any problem if there is space between first and last boxes in a row with the screen width?

Comment: @BimalPariyar no, issues but how it possible?

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH You can set equal margin by using `justify-content` property and you can also use `margin:auto` on a flex item to always have equal margins.

Please read about how `flexbox` works.

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH If you don't want to use media queries, then you might have to set the width of flex items in pixels rather than using percentage values. But it is better to use media queries

Comment: @Soothran thanks for the suggestion but I need not use media query any other way?

Comment: @Isisco please check i was update code for this issues without responsive media query.

Comment: @Soothran please check i was update code for this issues without responsive media query.

Comment: @BimalPariyar please check i was update code for this issues without responsive media query.

Answer (score 0):

Use justify-content?

```
justify-content:space-evenly;
```

Comment: but what about the responsive view? it's not a proper way.

Comment: it should be responsive. you should set ```flex-basis:100%;``` on the flex container also

Comment: also set ```margin-left:1.5%;``` and ```margin-right:1.5%;``` on flex-item

Comment: yes we can set the only desktop but what about responsive we can set in mobile view its show one div and tablet 2 div ? is it possible to set flex?

Comment: it depends on the tablet. you would use a media query to set the ```min-width``` of ```flex-item``` on breakpoint. eg. ```@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){.flexcontainer-item{min-width:44%;}}``` or something like that

Comment: thanks  but I already mentioned in the question that we don't need a responsive media query. any other way?

Comment: you need to set min-width:; to px measurment. if you do not want to use mediaquery

Comment: but width percentage how can set the whole screen proper width and gap for all device and desktop view?

Comment: You need to know your content. If you do not want to use a media query.

Comment: meaning...if i have a image in ```flexcontainer-item``` that has a width of 100px, and that is the biggest element inside the container. I can set the min-width of that ```flex-container-item``` to 100px, but scale it to 30.33%. that way you can have it automatically break in different viewpoints without a media query

Comment: It doesn't matter either content or box. both are CSS the same applied.

Comment: ```.flexcontainer-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30.33%;
  min-width:100px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  /*margin-right: 3%; removed*/
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}```

Comment: By not setting a specific width to your ```flexcontainer-item``` it will always scale to the width percentage you set, and will never break.

Comment: thanks but you're last two div it's not left-aligned other display like. it is not displayed center align.

Comment: please check i was update code for this issues without responsive media query.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `border-right` for flex item and add `justify-content: space-evenly;` to flex container:

here is the updated fiddle:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  /*added*/
}

.flexcontainer-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30.33%;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  /*margin-right: 3%; removed*/
  margin-bottom: 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes we can set the only desktop but what about responsive we can set in mobile view its show one div and tablet 2 div ? is it possible to set flex?

Comment: please check i was update code for this issues without responsive media query.

Answer (score 0):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; 
}
.flexcontainer {
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: row;
   flex-direction: row;
   -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
   flex-wrap: wrap;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.flexcontainer-item {
    height: 100px;
    width: 30.33%;
    background: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: inline-flex;
    margin: 0% 1.5% 3% 1.5%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: thank you for an answer. can you see the last two div is not proper? they must be left aligned.

Comment: and what about responsive?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flex CSS</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
    <style type="text/css">
        *{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .flexcontainer {
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-direction: row;
            flex-direction: row;
            -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
            flex-flow: row wrap;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }
        .flexcontainer-item {
            height: 100px;
            width: calc(30.33% - 3%);
            background: #ccc;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            /*margin-right: 3%;*/
            margin-bottom: 3%;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good try but we can set in mobile view its show one div and tablet 2 div ? is it possible to set flex?

Comment: You may have to add some javascript for that.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but  I want to only pure CSS and not to used javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I have set a max-width of `330px` to the flex items. This may not be the perfect answer. But it might resolve your issues.

You can the max-width value according to your requirements which best fits in all screens responsively.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexcontainer {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  margin: 0 3%;
}

.flexcontainer-item {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 330px;
  background: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto 3%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexcontainer">
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
  <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the try but you're the last two div it's not left-aligned other display like. it is not displayed center align.

Comment: any other way you know?

Comment: @HAPPYSINGH Sorry, you have to use either media query or javascript for this. I wonder why you don't want to use media queries. It is not that much complex

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all to give valuable time. I just want to share my knowledge. here an example for without responsive media query please check how it is work. If you understand this example please flag up or vote it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flex CSS</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
    <style type="text/css">
       * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }

        .flexcontainer {
            display: grid;
            grid-gap: 30px;
            grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(265px, 1fr));
            grid-auto-rows: 150px;
            grid-auto-flow: row dense;
            line-height: 20px;
        }

        .flexcontainer-item {
            position: relative;
            display: -webkit-box;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
            -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
            -webkit-box-pack: end;
            -ms-flex-pack: end;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            background: #0c9a9a;
            color: #fff;
            grid-column-start: auto;
            grid-row-start: auto;
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<div class="flexcontainer">
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
    <div class="flexcontainer-item"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Note: In IE browser is not support Grid properties. in future its must be work.